# Error attempting to use Streaming Api to query PushTopic

Tags: streaming-api, node.js, nforce

When I run my program using nForce to connect to the client I get this error...

> 400::The replayId for channel {/topic/mypushtopic} wasn't found using
>   the " +
>       'provided replay ID map {{}}. Ensure that the channel name you provided in ' +
>       'the replay map is valid and matches the channel name used for subscribing.

When I run in the Workbench it returns the JSON fine, but when running in node it is asking for replayID Map? I am also subscribed to the correct pushTopic. Help Please. Thanks.

Here is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./config.js');
var nforce = require('nforce');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
// attach socket.io and listen
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
// get a reference to the socket once a client connects
var socket = io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { });

var DEFAULT_REPLAY_ID = -1;


var org = nforce.createConnection({   clientId: config.CLIENT_ID,   clientSecret: config.CLIENT_SECRET,   redirectUri: config.CALLBACK_URL
+ '/oauth/_callback',   autoRefresh: true,   environment: 'production',   apiVersion: 'v44.0',   mode: 'single' });


org.authenticate({ username: config.USERNAME, password: config.PASSWORD }, function(err, oauth) {

  if(err) return console.log(err);
  if(!err) {
    console.log('*** Successfully connected to Salesforce ***');
// add any logic to perform after login
  }

  const client = org.createStreamClient();

  const sub = client.subscribe({ topic: 'AccountUpdates' });

  //subscribe to a pushtopic
 //var str = org.stream({ topic: config.PUSH_TOPIC, oauth: oauth });

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('streaming client transport: up');
  });

  client.on('disconnect', function (data) {
console.log('streaming disconnect: ' + data.reason);
console.log('disconnect data', data);
  });

  sub.on('connect', function () {
console.log('connected to topic: ' + sub.getTopic());   });

  sub.on('error', function (error) {
console.log('error: ' + error);
sub.cancel();
client.disconnect();   });

  sub.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log('current replay id: ' + sub.getReplayId())   });


});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err); });

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
}); }

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
}); });


server.listen(app.get('port'), function() {   console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env')); });

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading nforce documentation, it appears you only need to add `replayId: -2` in the parameter object when you called `client.subscribe`. -2 means all saved messages, and -1 means new messages only.

Answer (score -1):

Just use python and save yourself the time. It has various libraries that utilize the streaming API. Very easy to use.

Comment: Please add at least one specific example or this answer is likely to be deleted by the community.